# How to insert/edit records in Yii2 GridView, similar to ASP.Net

Tags: gridview, activerecord, insert, yii2, edit

In ASP.Net, we can make the GridView edit/update or delete a row, and insert (using footer). Can I do something similar in Yii2, instead of creating one record at a time in a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gridview provided by default does not allow this behavior. For this type of features you can use Extensions as  [Tabular From](http://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form)

These extension are easily configurable and free

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 GridView there is an action grid column as Shown:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'name',
            'price',
            'image',
            'area',
            // 'address',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Just place the last line ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'], in your gridview.

Comment: Yes, but ActionColumn edits the record on a new page, not on the gridview itself. As scaisEdge said, it cannot be done, but looking for alternate widgets that other people can suggest

Comment: Please Visit http://webtips.krajee.com/setup-editable-column-grid-view-manipulate-records/. Hope this solves your problem.